# Trouble with gettext windows and domain

Tags: python, internationalization, wxpython

I have a problem with gettext on windows.
I'm using gettext module from python and the 3rd part module named gettext_windows:
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~bialix/gettext-py-windows/trunk/view/head:/gettext_windows.py
THe code is the following:

```
    gettext_windows.setup_env()
    _ = gettext.gettext
    self._appName = "bitbucket"
    self._localeDir = os.getcwd() + "\\data\\locale\\"
    self._languages = ["it_IT", "pl_PL"]
    if gettext_windows.get_language()[0] in self._languages:
        lang = gettext_windows.get_language()[0]
    self._translation = gettext.translation(self._appName, self._localeDir, lang)
    self._translation.install(unicode=True)
```

For create a *.po/*.mo files im using PoEdit.
Then i save these files and i put them in:

```
data
----locale/
--------it_IT/
------------LC_MESSAGES/
----------------bitbucket.mo
----------------bitbucket.po

data
----locale/
--------pl_PL/
------------LC_MESSAGES/
----------------bitbucket.mo
----------------bitbucket.po
```

When i trying to execute my app i have the followed error:

> No translation files found for domain bitbucket

Can anybody explain me what's wrong?

THe files are in good directory.

IF i trying to user find() method from gettext module:

```
print gettext.find('bitbucket', self._localeDir, self._languages, all=True)
```

It work properly and returns *.mo files for it_IT/pl_PL language

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following the instructions on the wxPython wiki: http://wiki.wxpython.org/Internationalization#How_to_get_gettext_tools_for_Win32

If you get stuck, ask for help on the wxPython mailing list. There are multiple people there who have written this kind of support into their applications.

Comment: i have used this tutorial.i fixed my problem now translations works fine.But when i set the codeset it doesn't work properly.So how can i change codeset for my current language?
How can i change translations language?

Comment: I haven't done this sort of thing which is why I referred you to the wxPython mailing list.